# Understanding linear systems with infinite solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I came across following excerpt:

> Consider linear system $Ax=v$. $A$ is a transformation matrix.
> (a) If $|A|=0$, then there will be infinite vectors $x$ which transform to v.
> (b) If $|A|\neq 0$, then there will be single vector $x$ which transform to v.

I am not able to visualize (a).
I know following

1. $|A|=0$ if rank of $A\lt n$, where $n$ is dimension of system
2. If rank of $A$ is $R$, then we have $R$ number of $(n-1)$ dimensional planes. That is in 3D, if rank of $A$ is 2, then we will have $R=$ 2 planes each $3-1=2$ dimensional:
   [image]    [image]
   **Fig.1** ($u + v + w = 2, 2u + 2v +2w = 4, 3u + v + 4w = 6$)
   If rank of $A$ is 1 then we will have single 2 dimensional plane:
   [image]   [image]
   **Fig.2** ($u + v + w = 2; 2u + 2v +2w = 4; 3u + 3v + 3w = 6$)
   In column pictures, we will have vectors beloging to the same plane as can be seen in above blue vector images.

**Q1.** In above two examples, I have given $A$ and $v$. Can someone please explain with examplpe, in each of these two cases, how we can have infinite number of vectors $x$, such that $Ax=v$?

**Update:**

I want to add two more questions:

I also read:

> $|A|=0$ if $A$ squishes the whole space into lower dimension.

**Q2.** What does that mean in above two examples? Does it mean that if we multiply $A$ of fig 1 by some vector $x$, we will get $v$ belonging to same plane and in case of fig 2, to the same line?

(Also I guess, above we have to make assumption that $v$ belong to same plane as vectors of $A$ for infinite solution, as otherwise there will be no solution. I wanted to discuss infinite solution scenarios.)

Comment: Why can we rule out that there is no vector transformed to $v$ ? A linear equation system can also have no solution.

Comment: Yes I edited the question to add a note at the end: "we have to make assumption that $v$ belong to same plane as vectors of $A$ for infinite solution, as otherwise there will be no solution. I wanted to discuss infinite solution scenarios." This sounds correct, right?

Comment: Is $|A|$ the determinant of $A$ ? This only makes sense if the matrices are square matrices. If we know that the solution is not unique , a single solution already guarantees infinite many solutions.

Comment: Yes $|A|$ means determinant of $A$ and am dealing with square matrices. I also know we are dealng with infinitely many solutions. For Q1 in my original question, I said, I want example to visualize set of infinite number of solution vectors $x$. For Q2 in my original question, I want Yes No answer (for fig 1, $v$ belong to same plane and for fig 2, $v$ belong to same line) and reason if answer is No.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a square matrix. The following are equivalent:

- $\det A = 0$
- $A$ has full rank
- $A$ is invertible

So if $\det A = 0$, $A$ doesn't have full rank. By the rank-nullity theorem, the null space has nonzero dimension, so it has infinitely many vectors. So if the system $Ax = v$ has a solution $x'$, it has infinitely many solutions, because we can always add on another vector $u$ in the null space to get another solution $x' + u$: $A(x' + u) = Ax' + Au = Ax' + 0 = v$.

Also, if $\det A = 0$, then "$A$ squishes the whole space into lower dimension" because $A$ not having full rank means that the dimension of the column space is less than the dimension of the domain (again, this follows from the rank-nullity theorem). If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, we can think of it as a mapping from $n$-dimensional space to $n$-dimensional space. The column space of $A$, i.e. the subspace of all vectors that can be reached by $A$, has dimension less than $n$, so $A$ "squishes" $n$-dimensional space into something of a lower dimension.

Conversely, if "$A$ squishes the whole space into lower dimension", this means some vectors aren't hit by $A$, so $A$ is not invertible, so $\det A = 0$.

Comment: "some vector of set $V$ arent hit by $A$" - You mean, $A$ does not transform any vector of vector space to some vectors in same space. So inverse cannot exist as some vectors in its domain are not mapped to any. **Q3.** Right? For Q1 in my original question, I said, I want example to visualize set of infinite number of solution vectors $x$. For Q2 in my original question, I want Yes No answer (for fig 1, $v$ belong to same plane and for fig 2, $v$ belong to same line) and reason if answer is No.